# Как получить текст из bytea PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

Есть база PostgreSQL, в ячейках с типом bytea содержится текст, который запросом Select получается в виде "\310\355\352\340\361\"... как получить нормальную кодировку? Перепробовал все варианты с convert_from и encode которые нагуглил...

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вам необходимо знать, какая кодировка использовалась для кодирования текста. На вид похоже на windows-1251.

```
select convert_from('\310\355\352\340\361'::bytea, 'windows-1251');
```

Что даёт строку `Инкас`